# How to find all places a ruby model is still actively used inside a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have 10 tables that are no longer being used in our rails app. They used to be very integral to the business (billing related tables), but we've moved onto a new system.

I'm trying to find all the places in our rails app that actively call references to these models, so I can remove the code before dropping the tables. I'm trying to find a way to get notified anytime something calls the classes I need to remove. I've started with the model callback `after_initialize` and running a method that notifies our error tracking system with the call stack:

```
Class Transaction
  after_initialize :notify_of_initialize
  .
  .

    def notify_of_initialize
      Rollbar.info("Transaction Initialized. Need to deal with before removing from codebase.")
    end
end
```

This works ok, but doesn't tell me when scopes or class methods are called.  Or when another class calls an association (which happens a lot)

```
Order.first.transactions
```

thanks for the help

Comment: why don't you just do a project-wide search

Comment: yes.. do a `ctrl+shift+f` search with sublime for `Order` case sensitive and exact word.. all the places where you are calling a method on that `Model` will be listed

Comment: Yes, this was my first thought. I can't actually just search for `Order`. We have a pretty large code base, I've seen order instances set to variables like `order`, `o`, `current_order`, `latest_o`, and lots of other things.

Comment: Also searching for `transaction` is hard because we have a number of tables that have related columns with transaction information that we still want to keep. Like on the Orders table we'll have a `transaction_amount`, and `transaction_date`. Its basically pretty overwhelming to just search.